# SSRS Report Column Sorting

Tags: reporting-services

I've ask this question before but I want to do this from a different approach right now.

```
-- load test data
declare @YourTable table(ID char(4),Name char(1),L1 char(1),D1 int,L2 char(1),D2 int,L3            char(1),D3 int)
insert into @YourTable values
('AAAA','C','X',2,'Y',4,null,null),
('BBBB','D','Y',5,'Z',6,null,null),
('CCCC','E','X',3,'Y',6,'Z',9),
('DDDD','F','Z',5,'X',6,'Y',3)
```

which looks like this when the query to select this table is executed:

```
ID   |Name  | Label1| Data1 |L2 |D2 |L3 | D3|
AAAA | C    | X     | 2     | Y | 4 |   |   |
BBBB | D    | Y     | 5     | Z | 6 |   |   | 
CCCC | E    | X     | 3     | Y | 6 | Z | 9 |
DDDD | F    | Z     | 5     | X | 6 | Y | 3 |
```

I want to display in a report like so:

```
ID   |Name  | X | Y | Z | 
AAAA | C    | 2 | 4 | 0 |
BBBB | D    | 0 | 5 | 6 |
CCCC | E    | 3 | 6 | 9 |
DDDD | F    | 6 | 3 | 5 |
```

Ron Smith kindly suggested pivoting, which works nicely if I have a set amount of Label Data. However, if I have more Labels, how would I go about doing it in a report? I tried column groups but am kind of lost because i can't get it to sort.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is maximum label columns (L1, L2, L3 not X,Y,Z) you have? Do you know all the label data values (X,Y,Z....)?

Comment: It's not fixed. Not all are known.

Comment: Does that mean you don't know the table structure (not data) of **@yourtable**?

Comment: @yourtable has L1, D1, L2, D2...., L26, D26. But the data in L1, L2, L3...L26 is not just 26 different data, it can have A, B, C, D.....,Y, Z, AA,AB, AC.... So the labels and data per row is limited to 26 but the labels itself is not limited to 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would add multiple UNION ALL clauses into the Dataset SELECT statement e.g.

`SELECT ID, Name, Label1 AS Label, Data1 AS Data
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, L2 AS Label, D2 AS Data
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, L3 AS Label, D3 AS Data`

Then in the tablix I would add a column group on Label.  The Column Group will appear at the bottom right in Visual Studio.  This has Properties including Sort Order.

Comment: This would have been an ok answer if there was not millions of records and about 26 labels each, and this Union would cause a system crash. Sorry I did not clarify.

Comment: Wow - a "system crash".  Really? So you've tried it already.  26m rows or even several multiples of that should not be an issue for any commodity server.

Comment: Not sure why though. Also, it can cause the retrieval process to timeout. A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

Comment: If you are using Report Manager, you can remove the report timeout - under Processing Options. Perhaps you should rethink your choice of tool - an output of millions of rows and hundreds of columns is stretching the definition of a "report".